Explanation of multiple constraints from one rule
I'm trying to understand this case study:
https://github.com/DorisRipley/Art-Exhibition-Optimization-A-BIP-Modeling-Approach/blob/main/Art%20Exhibition%20Optimization.pdf
and I'm having trouble with this statement: "He
therefore wants at least one wire mesh sculpture displayed if a computer-generated drawing is displayed.
Alternatively, he wants at least one computer-generated drawing displayed if a wire mesh sculpture is displayed"
I know this can be a classic integer linear programming case, but i have no idea how that sentence can be expressed in the following constraints:
Now we can define the other constraints
\begin{align}
_1 + _2 + _3 &\le M _2 \\
_1 + _2 + _3 &\ge _2 \\
_4 + _5 &\le M _1 \\
_4 + _5 &\ge _1 \\
_2 + (1 − _1) &\le 1 \\
_1 + (1 − _2) &\le 1
\end{align}
Any hints?

Please, use the MathJax Tutorial

The use of the word "alternatively" is a bit funky, but basically what is being said is this: if there is at least one exhibit of either computer generation or wire mesh, then there must be at least one exhibit of the other type.
$x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ selected wire mesh pieces while $x_4$ and $x_5$ select computer generated pieces. The first two constraints define $y_2.$ If $y_2 = 0$ (no wire mesh pieces displayed), then $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$. If $y_2 = 1$ (at least one wire mesh piece displayed), then the number of wire mesh pieces displayed ($x_1 + x_2 + x_2$) is between 1 and 3. (You can, and should, take $M=3$ in the first constraint.) The third and fourth constraints define $y_1$ similarly (using $M=2$ this time).
The fifth constraint says that out of exhibiting a wire mesh piece ($y_2 = 1$) and not exhibiting a computer generated piece ($y_1 = 0$, or equivalently $1-y_1 = 1$), you cannot do both. The sixth constraint says that out of exhibiting a computer generated piece and not exhibiting a wire mesh piece, you cannot do both. Note that it would be mathematically equivalent (and perhaps clearer?) to replace the fifth and sixth constraints with $y_1=y_2$ (either exhibit both types or neither type).

You want to enforce the logical proposition
$$(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) \iff (x_4 \lor x_5) \tag1\label1$$
One approach is to introduce binary decision variables $y_1$ and $y_2$ and enforce
\begin{align}
(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) &\iff y_2 \\
(x_4 \lor x_5) &\iff y_1 \\
y_2 &\iff y_1
\end{align}
Equivalently, enforce
\begin{align}
(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) &\implies y_2 \\
y_2 &\implies (x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) \\
(x_4 \lor x_5) &\implies y_1 \\
y_1 &\implies (x_4 \lor x_5) \\
y_2 &\implies y_1 \\
y_1 &\implies y_2
\end{align}
The six given linear constraints do that.
Notice that the final two constraints reduce to $y_1=y_2$, so you could eliminate $y_2$ to obtain
\begin{align}
(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) &\implies y_1 \\
y_1 &\implies (x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) \\
(x_4 \lor x_5) &\implies y_1 \\
y_1 &\implies (x_4 \lor x_5)
\end{align}

Alternatively, you can avoid introducing new variables and instead somewhat automatically derive linear constraints from \eqref{1} via conjunctive normal form as follows.  First, rewrite \eqref{1} as
\begin{align}
(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) &\implies (x_4 \lor x_5) \tag2\label2\\
(x_4 \lor x_5) &\implies (x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Next, rewrite \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} as
\begin{align}
x_1 &\implies (x_4 \lor x_5) \\
x_2 &\implies (x_4 \lor x_5) \\
x_3 &\implies (x_4 \lor x_5) \\
x_4 &\implies (x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) \\
x_5 &\implies (x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) 
\end{align}
Equivalently,
\begin{align}
\lnot x_1 &\lor x_4 \lor x_5 \\
\lnot x_2 &\lor x_4 \lor x_5 \\
\lnot x_3 &\lor x_4 \lor x_5 \\
\lnot x_4 &\lor x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3 \\
\lnot x_5 &\lor x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3 
\end{align}
These yield linear constraints
\begin{align}
(1-x_1) + x_4 + x_5 &\ge 1\\
(1-x_2) + x_4 + x_5 &\ge 1\\
(1-x_3) + x_4 + x_5 &\ge 1\\
(1-x_4) + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &\ge 1\\
(1-x_5) + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &\ge 1
\end{align}
Simplifying yields
\begin{align}
x_1 &\le x_4 + x_5 \\
x_2 &\le x_4 + x_5 \\
x_3 &\le x_4 + x_5 \\
x_4 &\le x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \\
x_5 &\le x_1 + x_2 + x_3 
\end{align}
You can optionally aggregate to obtain the smaller but weaker system
\begin{align}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &\le 3(x_4 + x_5) \\
x_4 + x_5 &\le 2(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) 
\end{align}
